# Basic Substitution in SendGrid Dynamic Template

Tags: sendgrid-api-v3, sendgrid-templates

I am using the latest Java API to set dynamic template data into my SendGrid Email Templates.
However though i am passing the values correctly ( *i am able to see the sent dynamic values in the web dashboard)*, yet the value is not getting 'expressed' when the mail is being generated.

I tried with both HTML editor as well as Code editor , following the steps in the documentation . Java code is as below.

```
    personalization0.addTo(new Email("ron@xxxxx", "Ron Abraham"));
    personalization0.addDynamicTemplateData("otpvalue", "123456");
    mail.addPersonalization(personalization0);
    mail.setTemplateId("<templateid>");
```

HTML Code in SendGrid web editor

```
<span style="color: #000; font-size: 18px">OTP Value : {{ otpvalue }} </span></div>
```

In the web dashboard , when i check the sent mail i see otpvalue is being passed to the template.

[image]

I guess there is somethign missing in the way the value gets written into the HTML Dynamic Template . Any pointers ?

EDIT - Pasting the full method code below

```
    @PostMapping("/sendDynamicMail")
@PreAuthorize("#oauth2.hasScope('signup')")
public Response sendDynamicMailviaSendGridApi() throws IOException{

    String API_KEY = "SG.**********";
    
    Email from = new Email("*****@*****.com");
    String subject = "Test Dynamic Mail from Development team";
    Email to = new Email("ron@*****.com");

    Content content = new Content("text/html","Replace Body Content with Dynamic Template");
    
    Mail mail = new Mail(from,subject,to,content);
    mail.setReplyTo(from);
    Personalization personalization0 = new Personalization();
    
    personalization0.addTo(new Email("ron+1@*****", "Ron Abraham"));
    personalization0.addDynamicTemplateData("otpvalue", "666666");
    

    mail.addPersonalization(personalization0);
    
    //design first one template
    mail.setTemplateId("d-6dc6223eebfc49b7b887cac1c0f34fa2");
    
    
    SendGrid  sg = new SendGrid(API_KEY);
    
    Request request = new Request();
    Response response;
    
    try {
        
        request.setMethod(Method.POST);
        request.setEndpoint("mail/send");
        request.setBody(mail.build());
        response = sg.api(request);
          System.out.println(response.getStatusCode());
          System.out.println(response.getBody());
          System.out.println(response.getHeaders());
          
          return response;
    }
    catch(IOException io) {
        throw io;
    }
    finally {
        //do nothing
    }
}
```

Here is how the HTML Dynamic Template Looks . I have tried using the otp value in several places.

```
<div style="font-family: inherit; text-align: center"> <span style="color: #000; font-size: 18px">OTP Value1 : {{ otpvalue }} </span></div>
```

Comment: That's odd. Are you able to [use the template editor to test the data](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/sending-email/editor#test-data) and see it rendered correctly?

Comment: template editor to test substitution via handlebars is not available for design editor, only code editor.  Code editor the {{ otpvalue }} substitution works fine.

Comment: The [instructions for using test data in the design editor is here](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/sending-email/editor#test-data-with-the-design-editor).

Comment: thx. I am able to see the test data for design editor as well. It works fine in test data mode. I suspect i am not passing the json payload correctly. That could be the only reason. Is there a way to inspect the json data payload. Currently i see the payload on the dashboard (email activity more details) and i see otpvalue as one of the parameters.

Comment: interestingly , when i check the email activity section the 'Unique Args' section does not list 'otpvalue' since 19th August afternoon . It was getting set nicely until then.Not sure where the issue is. Does twilio restrict dynamic template variables for some reason, would be good to know.

Comment: I'm not sure you're seeing the right thing in the dashboard. [Unique arguments](https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/sending-email/unique-arguments) are used to track emails as they are sent to your as part of the event webhook. Can you share the full method you're using for creating an email? Those 4 lines look fine, but there might be an issue in the rest of the code.

Comment: Rather than using the constructor that takes from, to, subject and content, can you try the same but with just the empty constructor `Mail()`? That way you don’t need to create content you don’t use, and a `to` you don’t intend to send to.

Comment: I found the issue. thanks . it was to do with the way the payload was being constructed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue was how the personalization data was being passed.
`personalization0.addDynamicTemplateData("dynamic_template_data", "{otpvalue:454545}" );` 
earlier i was passing the otp value directly as as key value pair.
On analyzing the format which was being sent via curl , i made the change in java and it has worked.

Comment: Oh wow, this doesn't seem right! I'll raise this with the SendGrid library team.